# How to get if child category of this category is empty?

Tags: taxonomy

How I can know if the child categories of current categories are empty ?

I am using below code to filter out categories having no products and having no categories.

```
 $re_child_terms = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'category' );
        if ( $term->count > 0 || ! empty( $re_child_terms ) ) {
```

now want to filter out empty children categories here, is it possible ? how ?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to loop over the `$re_child_terms` array. According the docs [get_term_children](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) returns an array of term_ids so you will need to loop over the ids, get the terms and save them into a new array if they're not empty.

```
$re_child_term_ids = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'category' );
$re_child_terms = array();

foreach ( $re_child_terms_ids as $child_id ) {
    $child = get_term($child_id);
    if ( is_object($child) && !($child instanceof WP_Error) ) {
        if ( $child->count > 0 ) {
            $re_child_terms[] = $child;
        }
    }
}

if ( $term->count > 0 || !empty($re_child_terms) ) {
    // do stuff
}

// note: this code is untested but should work
```

**EDIT** (encapsulated into a function):

```
// in functions.php
if ( ! function_exists ) {
    function get_nonempty_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ) {
        $child_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );
        $child_objs = array();

        foreach ($child_ids as $id) {
            $child = get_term($id);
            if ( is_object($child) && !($child instanceof WP_Error) ) {
                if ( $child->count > 0 ) {
                    $child_objs[] = $child;
                }
            }
         }

         return $child_objs;
     }
}

// in template
$re_child_terms = get_nonempty_term_children($term->term_id, 'category');

if ( $term->count > 0 || !empty($re_child_terms) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I am already inside few loops as you can see using same condition that you have recommended, but  would like to know if there is any better way .

Comment: You are using the same condition as in my example but your original post is missing the foreach loop before it which is the critical point of my example.

What exactly do you mean by a 'better' way? more succinct?computationally faster?etc

To save yourself some time and effort and make you code more succinct you could encapsulate the functionality into a function

Comment: I have left those foreach loops. do not want another loop.

Comment: get_term_children() will return an empty array if no terms are found. So it's not clear why you need anything more. Maybe if you added the part where the condition of childlessness was coming into play, it would be more clear or answerable.